# Help with a differential amplifier

Tags: amplifier

So I have this differential amplifier and I need to know what's the Av and the Zin seen from vin(t). And how would a current source replace RE while having the same current in IE? [image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. However, this is not an online question solving platform. Provide how did you approach to the problem, what have you done, where did you stuck exactly at.

Comment: Joe - a formula for the differential gain (and its derivation) can be found in each textbook dealing with electronics....did you have a look?